# Addition by ZERO - PHP

Tags: php

Could somebody please tell me why `$total_value` evaluates to ZERO when either `$bawtry_value` or `$chain_value` are non-zero values?

**PHP**

```
    $bawtry_value = utf8_encode(money('%n', $bawtry * $price));

    echo "Bawtry Value";
    echo '<br />';
    echo $bawtry_value;
    echo '<br />';

    $chain_value = utf8_encode(money('%n', $chain * $price));


    echo "Chain value";
    echo '<br />';
    echo $chain_value;
    echo '<br />';

    $total_value = utf8_encode(money('%n', $bawtry_value + $chain_value));

    echo "Total value";
    echo '<br />';
    echo $total_value;
    echo '<br />';
```

**Example Output**

```
Result Bawtry 0
Result Chain 2
Total Pairs 2

Bawtry Value
£0.00

Chain value
£39.90

Total value
£0.00
```

Is there a problem with PHP adding two figures together when one is ZERO?

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: bawtry_value is a **string**

Comment: You're adding two strings, not numbers. And PHP is notorious for its auto type conversions which may yield unexpected results.

Comment: If the two values have commas for decimal separator, PHP won't recognize them as numbers.

Comment: What does `money()` do?

Comment: @HamZa - money() is the money_format() php function. I just renamed it when using it in my code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - should I cast the strings as integers before trying the addition?

Comment: @aphextwix: Nope, you should use original floats for addition.

Comment: You should put in your question original variables values that you use for operations.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the fact that it is a string is not a problem per-se.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - sorry I'm not familiar with this rule. So should I cast the numbers as floats ...

Comment: @aphextwix no, you **SHOULD NOT CAST**, just use the original, unformatted values!

Comment: Why all the minuses ? I'm sure I'm not the only newbie to encounter this problem so this could be a useful question at some point. I couldn't find a similar question listed on Stack.

Comment: @HamZa - don't be rude! I'm not using number_format() and error_reporting E^ALL is enabled.

Comment: Just tell us: what exactly is the result of "£39.90" + "£0.00" supposed to be? `+` expects to work with **numbers**. "£39.90" is not a number!

Comment: @aphextwix My bad, this crappy windows doesn't have `money_format()`. So I assumed `number_format()`. Don't get me wrong, there are hundreds of silly questions getting in because OP's don't enable error reporting. You're probably a gem in the mud. That said, try to first do the calculations and at the end format such calculation with your favorite functions. Mixing the process is a pain. This is why I sometimes like strictly typed languages. Again, my excuses

Comment: @aphextwix It seems something is wrong with your settings. You should get that warning. [See demo](https://eval.in/171394).

Comment: @HamZa - thanks that's useful. I'll double-check my php.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should change this line:

```
$total_value = utf8_encode(money('%n', $bawtry_value + $chain_value));
```

into

```
$total_value = utf8_encode(money('%n', $bawtry * $price + $chain * $price));
```

or even

```
$total_value = utf8_encode(money('%n', $price * ($bawtry + $chain)));
```

Now in calculating `$total_value` you have currency symbol at the beginning of `$bawtry_value` and `$chaing_value` and if you add them, they are converted to 0.

You can see this if you try to display:

```
echo '£0.00' + '£39.90';
```

first character of those strings is `£` is converted to 0.

However if you try to do something like that

```
echo '2£0.00' + '39.90£';
```

result will be 41.90 because strings are converted to int until the first character that makes the string cannot be converted to int.